# Building a lab, interfaces file issue, networking service won't restart because of ifup

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, services, ifupdown

Hello (beginner to linux networking),

I'm trying to build a lab in VirtualBox with a Debian GLPI server for school, the VM has 2 network interfaces : a NAT one in dhcp (eth0) and the other one (intern) is in static for local network (eth1).

Dumb question but what is the difference between enp0s and eth ?

I tried this config :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
allow-hotplug eth0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
allow-hotplug eth1
address 172.16.2.56
netmask 255.255.255.192
network 172.16.2.0
gateway 172.16.2.62
broadcast 172.16.2.63
```

I lost internet when making changes to the eth1 card which is unfortunate cause i need it to build GLPI, i tried different confs but cannot make the networking service restart, ifup is breaking on the address line : misplaced option.

Basically i want my NAT to come back and stay up so i can have internet on my VM + having eth1 for local purpose and hosting the GLPI ITSM service.

I don't know if i made it clear, if asked i will give you details, thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. While I don't have a solution to your actual issue, the difference between `ethN` and `enpXXX` is the transition from the old "kernel name" scheme (where glitches can lead to different names for the same interface issued at different boots) to the [predictable naming scheme](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.net-naming-scheme.html) for network interfaces.

Comment: Thank you ! I'm not used to post for solving issues i usually try to fix it myself but i'm kind of stuck, for the kernel thing I didn't thought about that it makes sense now